# Run IDL .pro from python Popen?

Tags: python, windows, idl-programming-language

Using a shell the following command works:
`idl -e 'eventtester, "TEST123", config_file="path/to/configuration.ini"'`

But when it is run from python through

```
pipes = subprocess.Popen('idl -e \'eventtester, "TEST123", config_file="path/to/configuration.ini"\'', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out, std_err = pipes.communicate()
pipes.wait()
```

The only output I get on stdout is:

```
IDL 8.7.0 (Win32 x86_64 m64).
(c) 2018, Harris Geospatial Solutions, Inc.

Licensed for use by: XXXXX
License: XXXXXXX
License expires XXXXX.
```

So it seems like IDL is just running without any arguments for some reason.
`eventtester.pro` is in the IDL lib path so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

*Edit*:
Not sure why but this is how I managed to get it to work:

```
pipes = subprocess.Popen('bash -c idl -e \'eventtester, "TEST123", config_file="path/to/configuration.ini"\'', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out, std_err = pipes.communicate()
pipes.wait()
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but have a look at the IDL-Python bridge: https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/python.html

Comment: I have looked into the official idlpy module but for some reason the IDL distribution provided by my institution does not have the dlls necessary to install it.    
I have also looked into other pip modules but they all don't work/don't support the windows platform.   
   
Thankfully I was able to solve my problem by adding `bash -c ` to my shell call